# Different PDF Invoices Magento1 - Shipping tax in total tax included/excluded

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf, shipping-tax

there are two ways, to create an invoice pdf, right?

The first is: Sales->Orders, open an order, go to "Invoices" on the left menue, choose the invoice and hit the button "print".

The second is: Sales->Orders, then check the Order you need the invoice of. Then go to the Actions-drow-down-field on top and choose "Print invoices".

The thing is: The pdfs are different, depending on the way I chose - in the first way the shipping tax is EXCLUDED in the field for 7% (that's exactly what I need the pdf to look like, both of them), in the second it's included.

Same with credit memos.

Why is that so? What could I have done wrong? 
How can I change that? I tried several things to change the amount in the pdf but couldn't find a solution. It's really frustrating..

Just for information: I've got a fresh Magento 1.9.3.1. installation with no optional extentions.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Tax-included:** Tax Included means you sell at the same price at all times in all countries. For example, if you sell an item for **100€** in one country would would sell it for the same price in all countries. The tax would be calculated after the payment depending on your customer (B or C, Country, threshold). If VAT/tax is due Octobat will deduct the amount from the **100€** you sold. Let’s say you sold to a german customer, VAT is **19%**.Meaning you will sell at different prices depending on the customers you have. Octobat will calculate: **100/1,19= 84,03€**, this amount is what you sold price excluded. The tax represent **100-84,03= 15,97€**

**Tax-excluded:** The excluded tax price will be all time the same, **100€** for instance. And tax will be calculated before payments and added to the excluded tax price depending on your customer (B or C, Country, threshold). If VAT/tax is due, Octobat will calculate it and add it on top of the **100€**. Let’s say you sell to a Italian customer, VAT is **22%**. Octobat will calculate: **100*1,22= 122€**. To enable you to sell tax-excluded Octobat offers

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I thinks that's not an answer to my question... Or I do not understand your post correctly.